# I want to have a text from one file written to the other file through pipes

Tags: c

The following is my code for the said task but the output file shows a bizarre output. Also, is there any way I can do it through system calls (write(), read(), etc.), I am intermingling the system calls and the C language functions but if someone wants to do it via system calls only, then what would the code be ? Thanks in advance! :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 512
#define READ_END 0
#define WRITE_END 1

int main(void)
{
int destination_fd;
FILE* fpinput;
char write_message[BUFFER_SIZE];
char read_message[BUFFER_SIZE];
ssize_t bytesRead, bytesWritten;
int fd[2];

if(pipe(fd) == -1)
{
printf("Unable to create the pipe\n");
return -1;
}

pid_t pid;
pid = fork();

if(pid == -1)
{
printf("Unable to create the process\n");
return -1;
}

if(pid > 0)
{
fpinput = fopen("input.txt", "r");
if(fpinput == NULL)
{
printf("Unable to open and read the file\n");
return -1;
}

int i = 0;
while(!EOF){
write_message[i] = fgetc(fpinput);
++i;
}

close(fd[READ_END]);
write(fd[WRITE_END], fpinput, BUFFER_SIZE);
close(fd[WRITE_END]);
fclose(fpinput);

wait(NULL);
}

if(pid == 0)
{
destination_fd = open("copy.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0700);
if(destination_fd == -1)
{
printf("Unable to open and write to the file\n");
return -1;
}

close(fd[WRITE_END]);
read(fd[READ_END], read_message, BUFFER_SIZE);
close(fd[READ_END]);
bytesWritten = write(destination_fd, read_message, BUFFER_SIZE);
close(destination_fd);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *multiple* problems.

First the problem you ask about: That you seem to receive "garbage" in the child-process. That's because you attempt to read into the buffer `write_message`, but then you write the `FILE` structure `fpinput` to the pipe.

---

A second problem is that you won't actually read anything, because `while(!EOF)` will *never* iterate. The symbolic constant `EOF` is replaced with the integer number `-1`, and when you apply the logical negation operator `!` to it you have the value `0` which is false.

I suggest you modify your loop to e.g.

```
int i = 0;
while ((write_message[i] = fgetc(fpinput)) != EOF)
{
    ++i;
}
```

Or perhaps

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE && (write_message[i] = fgetc(fpinput)) != EOF; ++i)
{
}
```

The second loop also include buffer overrun protection.

Comment: Thanks a lot fpinput was entered by mistake there. But one think that I did not understand much is that when I define BUFFER_SIZE to be 98, everything is perfect but increasing the size leads to the writing of strange characters in the file, could you please explain it a bit, with the first loop.